# Failed Openssh conenction

Tags: openssh

Hello i need help for solving sshd server or ssh client problame on my windows 10 OS.

In the following section check the log of --vvv option output:

```
PS C:\Users\dsafg> ssh dsafg@localhost -i $env:dsafg\ujkulcs -vvv
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/ujkulcs error:13
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/ujkulcs.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\dsafg\\ujkulcs type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/ujkulcs-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/ujkulcs-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\dsafg\\ujkulcs-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'dsafg'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:GF00dsg3nZEhyiyk96r9QwX6bgHJ5Fvgoyc9wSOl/bU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\dsafg/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\dsafg\\ujkulcs (0000000000000000), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\dsafg\\ujkulcs
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/dsafg/ujkulcs error:5
Load key "C:\\Users\\dsafg\\ujkulcs": Permission denied
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
dsafg@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I also provide EventViewer logs:

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp5Ht.jpg)

May have problame with the previously installed openssh server/client from

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp5Ht.jpg)

So there is remained Openssh Server/Agent service. I look in the Service manager.

Althought maybe it is not the source of problem becouse before it there wasn't more instances of different versions Openssh and agent.

The problem begin when as you look trying to use that key. But there is so many other problems like Failed to opens, like it wouldn't enought permission for it. But it have:

> Note: C:/Users/dsafg/.ssh/config not exist in real. There is no such file.

Check the ACL: everything is Full controll instead of some Authorized users group.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp5Ht.jpg)

Here is the content of ssh_config at ProgramData:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe
Subsystem powershell c:/progra~1/powershell/7-preview/pwsh.exe -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

The connection only works with password authentication, instead of now it is disabled for reason of trying to connect with public key.

I only test it in localhost but it already tested on android wifi client with same error. My MS account was added to Users, i hope this is not a problem, becouse it worked with it before.

First of all please help how to fuly unisntall the previous instance of clents of openssh than we can move forward.

This helped:

> $administratorsRule = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
> $systemRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
> $acl.SetAccessRule($administratorsRule)
> $acl.SetAccessRule($systemRule)

Comment: Uninstall OpenSSH from within the optional windows features and any other instances of OpenSSH you might have.  This will require a restart obviously.  Once you have a clean slate, reinstall OpenSSH, and reconfigure your OpenSSH to accept your keys. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication) script will help you accomplish that task.  Any image link you did not specifically upload to Imgur is currently inaccessible.

Comment: I fixed it check the img if you can

Comment: Comments are unformatted.  If you have anything vital to add, [edit] your question, instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your errors, it looks like you're having a permission problem. Try using `CACLS` on your Windows device and on your server use `chmod` (assuming your server is running Linux).

[This website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cacls) can help you with `CACLS`.

[This website](https://chmodcommand.com/) can help you generate `chmod` commands easily.

Comment: So it is a Windows server not Linux. So how to use thes commans please help me in it.
Which folder/files use the cals and how to use parameters of it?

Comment: You'd want to give the owner read, write, and execute permisisons to the ssh folder, and read and write to the owner to the contents of the ssh folder, I think. I haven't messed around much with cacls & Windows Server, but I think you'd do something along the lines of ` cacls folder /p user:f`

Comment: ssh folder you think to "C:\ProgramData\ssh" ? Just look at this:
https://kephost.net/p/2021/14/4746_9d76f11e208f.png
I think there is full controll already... But in my topic i give full detailed folder acls. Please check it if you have time.

Comment: Cacls was good but system note me it is deprecated. use icacls and need more information for use. So when i grant access to administrators how to do that? and need the (OM)(CI) and how to use that? Please post an example or ask someone to help. I want to lern that for further use.